# "text-align: center" not working with Media Query

Tags: wordpress

I have searched these boards to an extent I believe is thoroughly and am still have issues after trying a number of different solutions. I am using the Avada themes and using there shortcodes for some layout elements.

In my style.css I have the following

```
@media screen and (min-width: 980px) {
/* STYLES HERE */
 p1#p114 {
    font-family: Times; font-size !important;
    font-size: 380%;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-style: italic !important;
   text-shadow: 4px 4px 2px rgba(5, 5, 5, 0.75);
    line-height: 125%;}
```

In my page file I have the following code

```
[fullwidth backgroundcolor="" backgroundimage="http://dylanstevenscrawshaw.com/painterspaint/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/Colour-1.jpg" backgroundrepeat="no-repeat" backgroundposition="left top" backgroundattachment="fixed" video_webm="" video_mp4="" video_ogv="" video_preview_image="" overlay_color="" overlay_opacity="0.5" video_mute="yes" video_loop="yes" fade="no" bordersize="0px" bordercolor="" borderstyle="solid" paddingtop="100px" paddingbottom="100px" paddingleft="100px" paddingright="100px" menu_anchor="" equal_height_columns="no" hundred_percent="no" class="" id=""][fusion_text]<p1 id="p114"><strong>"COLOURS THAT SUIT YOU!"</strong></p>[/fusion_text][/fullwidth]
```

How would I go about entering the text within this element?

I realize I currently don't have any values in the posted code to try and (text-align: center;) I left it out as I new it was completely wrong from the results I was receiving.

I have tried a number of the solutions offered on this board and still have not managed to solve this.

I know I am missing something or doing something wrong and hope someone can help.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the ending curly bracket for the media query: `}`

```
@media screen and (min-width: 980px) {
/* STYLES HERE */
 p1#p114 {
    font-family: Times; font-size !important;
    font-size: 380%;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-style: italic !important;
   text-shadow: 4px 4px 2px rgba(5, 5, 5, 0.75);
    line-height: 125%;}
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, sorry I just realized the snippet I posted was missing that closing bracket as I have another style below it that I left out just for to keep things short. Even if I add text-align:center;  within the appropriate curly brackets I still am unable to center the text.

Comment: Then show the output code generated (view source on the page), as the input is only intelligible for users of the theme.